# Android Flavor Testing .R-file

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem with the .R-files of an app with 2 flavors:
"main" and "flavor1"

In "main" there is the common codebase. In "flavor1" there is some flavor-specific implementation.

and I have 2 test directories:
androidTest (package org.myapp.test)
androidTestFlavor1 (package org.myapp.flavor1.test)

In androidTest there is the common test codebase including resource files. In androidTestFlavor1 there are only tests specific to this flavor.

Now, I have the problem that when I execute the tests in androidTestFlavor1, Android Studio complains that it cannot find the .R-file of the common test codebase (which is imported and used only in the androidTest-directory) - "cannot resolve symbol R".

Obviously, the file org.myapp.test.R was not generated. Only org.myapp.flavor1.test.R was generated. Why is there only one .R-file generated? I thought the .R-file in the common directory should always be generated?

Comment: Hi, have you choose the good BuildVariant when you run your test ?

Comment: Hi! I have chosen flavor1Debug as BuildVariant

Comment: EDIT: I have noticed, that both .R-files (org.myapp.test.R and org.myapp.flavor1.test.R) have been generated. However, only the org.myapp.flavor1.test.R is active when choosing flavor1Debug as BuildVariant.

Is there a way to tell gradle to use only the file org.myapp.test.R? Maybe with SourceSets?

Comment: Have you tried to delete this file `flavor1.test.R` ? I know that if you have one file for each flavor gradle take the best one, so if one of them is deleted, gradle takes default file. I think.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to delete this file. It doesn't work because org.myapp.test.R seems to be excluded anyway when building for a specific flavor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found a solution for this. I've added the line testApplicationId 'org.myapp.test' to defaultConfig in build.gradle